# How to list resolvedDataSources from AbstractRoutingDataSource?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, multi-tenant

I implemented Dynamic DataSource Routing using Spring Boot (JavaConfig) to add and switch new DataSources in runtime.

I implemented AbstractRoutingDataSource and I need access to all resolvedDataSources that is a private property. How can I do it?

Comment: If it is a private property it is probably not meant to be accessed from outside of the class.

Comment: Is there anyway to access all mapped dataSources by Tenant?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know why that field has not been made *protected* to let implementing classes access the data sources set. Regarding your questions two options come into my mind.

**Option 1:**

Copy the code of `AbstractRoutingDataSource` into a class of your own. Then you can expose the `resolvedDataSources` simply by a *getter*. This should work as long as the configuration relies on the interface `AbstractDataSource` and not `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.

**Option 2**

Pick the brute force way by accessing the field via *Reflection API*